# Plotting residuals of masked values with `statsmodels`

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I'm using `statsmodels.api` to compute the statistical parameters for an OLS fit between two variables:

```
def computeStats(x, y, yName):
    '''
    Takes as an argument an array, and a string for the array name.
    Uses Ordinary Least Squares to compute the statistical parameters for the
    array against log(z), and determines the equation for the line of best fit.
    Returns the results summary, residuals, statistical parameters in a list, and the 
    best fit equation.
    '''

    #   Mask NaN values in both axes
    mask = ~np.isnan(y) & ~np.isnan(x)
    #   Compute model parameters
    model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x), missing= 'drop')
    results = model.fit()
    residuals = results.resid

    #   Compute fit parameters
    params = stats.linregress(x[mask], y[mask])
    fit = params[0]*x + params[1]
    fitEquation = '$(%s)=(%.4g \pm %.4g) \\times redshift+%.4g$'%(yName,
                    params[0],  #   slope
                    params[4],  #   stderr in slope
                    params[1])  #   y-intercept
    return results, residuals, params, fit, fitEquation
```

The second part of the function (using `stats.linregress`) plays nicely with the masked values, but `statsmodels` does not. When I try to plot the residuals against the x values with `plt.scatter(x, resids)`, the dimensions do not match:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

because there are 29007 x-values, and 11763 residuals (that's how many y-values made it through the masking process). I tried changing the `model` variable to

```
model = sm.OLS(y[mask], sm.add_constant(x[mask]), missing= 'drop')
```

but this had no effect.

How can I scatter-plot the residuals against the x-values they match with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @jim421616 Since statsmodels dropped few missing values, you should use the model's exog variable to plot the scatter as shown.

```
plt.scatter(model.model.exog[:,1], model.resid)
```

For reference a complete dummy example

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate data
x = np.random.rand(1000)
y =np.sin( x*25)+0.1*np.random.rand(1000)

# Make some as NAN
y[np.random.choice(np.arange(1000), size=100)]= np.nan
x[np.random.choice(np.arange(1000), size=80)]= np.nan


# fit model
model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x) ,missing='drop').fit()
print model.summary()

# plot 
plt.scatter(model.model.exog[:,1], model.resid)
plt.show()
```